# jsforce query on ContentVersion returns the url rather than Base64 value

Tags: contentversion, jsforce

I am using jsforce for fetching ContentVersionData from a Node app. My query is `SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion` but instead of fetching the base64 value in VersionData field i m getting an url.

Let me know how to fetch base64 value of multiple ContentVersion in one go.

=========================Connection Code ================================

```
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
        loginUrl : 'https://test.salesforce.com/'
    });
    await conn.login(username,password);
   req.conn = conn;
```

=======================================================================

==================Query Code ======================================

```
let conventVersion = await sfConnection.query('SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion');
    conventVersion.records.forEach(ele=> {
        console.log(ele.VersionData);
```

===========================================================================

=================Output Generated ========================

/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0685D000000YcdCQAS/VersionData
/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0685D000000YcdbQAC/VersionData
/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0685D000000Yd18QAC/VersionData
/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0685D000000YdIYQA0/VersionData
/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/0685D000000YfhzQAC/VersionData

Thanks

Comment: It's worth looking at the data model diagram of all the Contact Objects [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_content.htm) and the [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) tech docs

Comment: Hi Brian , Thanks for quick response . Looked at both the link you shared but not able figure how to do the same. Can you help me out ?

Comment: Can you please provide a code of your connection query and the returned results?

Comment: Hi Oleh updated the post with code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for JSForce responding back with the URLs is because JSForce is using the REST API and that won't return back the Base64 content. Salesforce's SOAP API will however though when you issue a query with a Base64  field.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bryan it worked!

Comment: Bryan, Can you let me know how put Set of Ids in query string in SOAP API when we have large set of ids? Stuck on ContentDocumentLink

Comment: @AjSyles I would suggest looking at using the `retrieve()` SOAP API call to perform what you are looking for https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_retrieve.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You are a saviour!